# Python & iTunes - Odd results

Tags: python, itunes

I'm using the iTunes wrapper here:
https://github.com/ocelma/python-itunes

```
def itunes_search(appname):
try:
    results = itunes.search(query=appname, media='software')
    result_count = len(results)
    return results, result_count
except:
    return -1
```

I'm querying the "software" category, as I'm only searching for apps.

The results work as expected for most games and apps, but certain ones (mostly those in the "Education" category) won't return as results even when explicitly searched for. It appears kind of random which ones will show up and which ones won't.

Example queries that don't return any expected results are [Reading Counts](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/reading-counts!/id689508301?mt=8) and [ModMath](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/modmath/id821892964?mt=8), both of which are returned in a regular Google query and feature iTunes pages.

"Reading Counts" as search term returns:

- Maria Counts Pumpkins - LAZ Reader [Level A-kindergarten]
- Scholastic Book Fairs
- Mickey Mouse Clubhouse: Mickey's Wildlife Count Along

... as the first three results, with the actual app itself being nowhere in the batch of 100 results.

Is this due to the wrapper I'm using, or is there something particular about those apps that they don't return in the query?

Comment: have you considered not catching the error that is raised and see if it might hold useful information?

Comment: It doesn't a raise an error in those cases, but the intended apps are completely absent from the returned results. "Reading Counts" for example yields Maria Counts Pumpkins - LAZ Reader [Level A-kindergarten], Scholastic Book Fairs and Mickey Mouse Clubhouse: Mickey's Wildlife Count Along as the first three results. You'd figure the first result would be Reading Counts explicitly, but it's completely absent in the 100 results I get back.

Comment: not sure why it doesn't come up but I get the same behaviour when I search for "Reading Counts" in the iTunes app store on my computer, but when I click on "open in iTunes" from the webpage you have linked to I get an error that the "Reading Counts!" app is not available in my country, maybe that is what is happening with your wrapper too.

Comment: Thank you for that! I'll add a feature to give it an ID directly; if you query for 689508301, it returns the correct app. Maybe I should contact Apple too and let them know, though odds are they're already aware of this.